# How to set threshold of random data

Tags: python, random, threshold

I have a set of values randomly distributed in interval **[a, b]**. How to set a threshold **a < c < b** such that **80%** values of this set are in **[a, c]**? Supposed that **a** = minimum value and **b** = maximum value of this set.

Comment: Lookup some examples of [generating random sampled data with skew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858290/random-variable-from-skewed-distribution-with-scipy)

Comment: Do you need values in [a,c] to follow a uniform distribution ? Same with numbers in ]c,b] ?

Comment: the dataset was generated before!

Comment: Sorry, totally misread your question ! :o Thought you vere trying to *generate* a dataset with such properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is the 80th [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) of your data set.

There are some code suggestions (both NumPy/SciPy and pure Python) in [How do I calculate percentiles with python/numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374640/how-do-i-calculate-percentiles-with-python-numpy)